# $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2m})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I want to show that if $m$ is odd, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2m})$, where $\zeta_m$ is the $m$-th root of unity, $\zeta_m=e^{2\pi i/k}$.

This is stated without proof in all the textbooks I've looked, so I guess it can't be very hard.

I'm able to prove it using the fact that $\Phi_{2n}(x)=\Phi_{n}(-x)$, but I'm looking for a more direct proof.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: $\zeta_k = \exp \frac{2\pi i}{k}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes. I'll make it more clear in the question.

Comment: Let $m = 2n+1$. Then $\zeta_m^{n+1} = - \zeta_{2m}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $m$ is odd, let $\zeta_m$ be a primitive $m^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of unity. Then $(-\zeta_m)^m = (-1)^m = -1$, so that $|-\zeta_m| = 2m$ and thus $-\zeta_m$ is a primitive $2m^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of unity.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for. I see that $-\zeta_m$ is a $2m$-th root of unity, but I don't quite get the primitive part. What does the notation $|-\zeta_m|$ mean?

Comment: I mean the order of $-\zeta_m$ - the smallest power that is equal to $1$. Clearly no smaller power of $-\zeta_m=1$, so $2m$ is the smallest such power --- this implies that $-\zeta_m$ is a primitive $2m$-root.